# can you help me translate this ??

Tags: translation

[image]

pls help me to translate this thnk you

Comment: It's not easy to translate a poem! For reference only: http://news.xinhuanet.com/edu/2004-04/02/content_1397026.htm

Comment: Isn't it kind of cut off at the bottom? `黄河远上白云间,一片孤城万仞山.羌笛何须怨杨柳,春风`

Comment: ty for help but nah its not cut ._.

Comment: ok is it simplified chinese or the traditional one ?

Comment: tank you everyone ^^ so much

Answer (score 1):

[【古诗英译】王之涣《凉州词》   译/晚枫](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_4fbe5af80100nf1c.html)

凉州词
王之涣

黄河远上白云间，
一片孤城万仞山。
羌笛何须怨杨柳，
春风不度玉门关。

Lyrics to Liangzhou Tune

by Wang Zhihuan
tr. Rhapsodia_晚枫

The Yellow River riseth up far into clouds so white,
An isolated city on mountains standeth sky-high.
The flute is futile the weeping willows tune here to blow,
In that beyond the Jade-gate Pass spring breezes never go.

第二版（12月12日）

The Yellow River riseth far into clouds white,
Atop a mountain standeth a lone fort at height.
Should the piccolo pick the willow tune to play?
Since over the Yumen Pass spring breeze reacheth nay.

经过这一番讨论，现在根据新的认识，拿出第三版，望各位批评：

The Yellow River reaches up to touch clouds white,
A lone fort sets far against the high mount in sight.
The weeping willow tune the flute needs not to play,
For yond the Yumen Pass spring breeze won’t make its way.

第四版 Dec 15 2010

The Yellow River reaches up into clouds white,
A lone fortress and a high mountain far in sight.
The weeping willow tune the flute needs not to play,
For yond the Yumen Pass spring breeze won’t make its way.